# audio record testing

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition, android-speech-api

I have a Google Speech API android project and I want to create test for the speech recognition but I don't see how I can do it, I saw that some people have the "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge" (audio.raw file) but I don't see how to use it in my test, any ideas?

Comment: Should I somehow mock the microphone?

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Please add some code.

Comment: That's the problem that I don't know how to send the audio.raw file as a microphone input in my code. I think I should do it using the MediaRecorder class but I don't know how to start. 

Sorry I'm a newbie using audio in android